# Why does this jquery simple transfer effect not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
 $(function () {
    $("#div1").click(function () {
        $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("#div2") }, 1000);
        //$(this).effect("shake", { times: 2 }, 200);
    });
});
```

The “shake” effect could work, but the transfer doesn't work so, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML. That may be the issue. As your js looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
var i = 1 - $( "div" ).index( this );
$( this ).effect( "transfer", { to: $( "div" ).eq( i ) }, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

Your probably missing some parts like the role of `var i`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

Ensure you have two divs with those respective IDs are on your DOM.  Also ensure you have a ui-effects-transfer class defined in your CSS, since a lack of this would make it appear like your event is doing nothing.

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r4RTH/

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="green"></div>
<div id="div2" class="red"></div>
```

JS:

```
 $("#div1").click(function () {
     $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("#div2") }, 1000);
     $(this).effect("shake", { times: 2 }, 200);
 });

$( "#div2" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).effect( "transfer", { to: $( "#div1" ) }, 1000 );
    $(this).effect("shake", { times: 2 }, 200);
});
```

CSS:

```
div.green {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

div.red {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.ui-effects-transfer {
    background-color: black
}
```